# split a spanned without space with Pattern on Android

Tags: java, android, split

I have a spanned like this :

```
Vallin, rue de FID1SHAPEPointVOIEVallin, rue deLOCALISATIONHauteur
 n°7PLACE_ELARGIENONETATEn placeDUREE<Null>NOMBRE_PLACES1CODE_VOIE<Null>
```

And I want to split the string to get the information after

```
"LOCALISATION", "PLACE_ELARGIE", "DUREE" and "NOMBRE_PLACES"
```

I'm using Pattern right now but I can't remove the elements that I want.

Thank you for your help,

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution here it is :

```
String desc2 = "Vallin, rue de FID1SHAPEPointVOIEVallin, ruedeLOCALISATIONHauteurn°7PLACE_ELARGIENONETATEn placeDUREE<Null>NOMBRE_PLACES1CODE_VOIE<Null>";
String split = "VOIE|LOCALISATION|PLACE_ELARGIE|ETAT|DUREE|NOMBRE_PLACES|CODE";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(split);
tokens = p.split(desc2);
```